# Sending and getting positions of device from a server

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, position, communication

I am pretty new to Objective-C and want to write an iPhone app.
The iPhone app should send the device-ID to a server when it is started the first time,
and even if the app is in the background, the device should send its position in a given time interval and the current position is stored with the ID.
If the iPhone is near a given other position, the server should send a message to the device such an alert view appears on the screen.

I don't expect a manual to program this, but I would be happy if you can give me some key words to look up and classes I definitely need to use.

Comment: upto my knowledge i am giving that device has id that we can get by [[UIDevice currentdevice]uniqueidentifier];

Answer (score 1):

Well, sounds like your gonna need the CoreLocation framework

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CoreLocation_Framework/_index.html

That'll handle the positioning of the device.

The UDID (device id) is fairly straight forward, a quick google will get you that code.

You'll also need to look into multitasking, specifically the link below, to execute code when the app is in the background.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html

Comment: How can i trigger a function on a server? and how are functions on a server written (what language)... what kind of server is appropriate?

Comment: a simple SOAP service or HTTP request would suit, you need to do your own research into web services, it's not an area of expertise I am well versed in.